# how can i load a directory of png in tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i have a directory of png files . there is a train folder and test folder . In the train folder i have 10 folders as 10 labels [ 0 -9 ] .Each folder contains  png files of that label . I want to load them in tensor flow for training . I am new in tensor flow i am having a very hard time getting this done

i am using anaconda ( py ver 3.5 )

```
import tensorflow as tf


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("./images/*.jpg"))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
```

i have tried using this but can make it work . it only loads 1 image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me though. Can you run this script ? (Updated to get Labels as well)

```
import tensorflow as tf
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
tf.train.match_filenames_once("/home/xxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/*/*.png"))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
S = tf.string_split([key],'/')
length = tf.cast(S.dense_shape[1],tf.int32)
# adjust constant value corresponding to your paths if you face issues. It should work for above format.
label = S.values[length-tf.constant(2,dtype=tf.int32)]
label = tf.string_to_number(label,out_type=tf.int32)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image_file)

# Start a new session to show example output.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Required to get the filename matching to run.
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in xrange(6):
        # Get an image tensor and print its value.
        key_val,label_val,image_tensor = sess.run([key,label,image])
        print(image_tensor.shape)
        print(key_val)
        print(label_val)


   # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
   coord.request_stop()
   coord.join(threads)
```

File Directory

```
./images/1/1.png
./images/1/2.png
./images/3/1.png
./images/3/2.png
./images/2/1.png
./images/2/2.png
```

Output:

```
 (881, 2079, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/3/1.png
 3
 (155, 2552, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/2/1.png
 2
 (562, 1978, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/3/2.png
 3
 (291, 2558, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/1/1.png
 1
 (157, 2554, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/1/2.png
 1
 (866, 936, 3)
 /home/xxxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/2/2.png
 2
```

Comment: Thank u very much ..it works but i dont get how the labels and its image's relation are handled

Comment: @FarshidRayhan, I added script to get labels for each image as well. Please run the script and verify the label - image pairs are correct. I hope this solves your task.

Comment: @FarshidRayhan, did my answer help you ?

Comment: Thank u very much ... i myself have already written one for myself using os walk and other stuff  ... But yours is much better

Comment: @FarshidRayhan, hey..please accept the answer if it is good enough for your task. Thanks.

Comment: I get all sort of error . Here is a link of the errors screen shot     https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mgklheottb5q64l/AADYFEsp6DhPw4UOLvPPNDUVa?dl=0

Comment: @FarshidRayhan, I can't see any error. I see only code.

Comment: how many png images you have in those folders ?? can you do "ls -LR" ? seems like you have only one image.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/frl5nwd0yvq97as/Screenshot%20from%202017-05-17%2004-51-36.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you provide correct path for images ? your images are in Desktop/labeled whereas you provided some other link in code. Please change the path and try.

Comment: the paths are correct . I though i made a error in the path so i changed it . But  the error remained the same .

Comment: can you do "ls -LR" at correct location ? Error just means it is not able to find images to load into TF queue.

Comment: also, please run key,label,image in one run as shown in above code. Dont use three runs. It might feed next value.

Comment: i have tried all that . i think the prb is in the string_to_number or tf.constant .... The error i get is "OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_1921_input_producer_65' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
  [[Node: ReaderReadV2_65 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2_65, input_producer_65)]] " .

Comment: It's strange. It works pretty well on my machine. Did you try with one image ? change the path to one single image and see.

Comment: no ... i have found that the label is doing the problem if i remove that it sometimes works ... I am not clear abt y it sometime works and sometime shows error though

Comment: I ran the script for more than 10 times and never faced the issue. I am using this kind of input pipeline for my training and testing. It never failed. I am using TF 1.0 and Py2.7. Is it some problem with version ??

Comment: i have TF 1.0.1 and py 3.5 .