# Assign label and id for images folder in python

Tags: image, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I have currently worked on machine learning model and i used CNN model for it. My project is signature detection in which each folder contains users signature(10 signature per user). I want to assign label and id to folder. structure is as follow

> Data-> Train-> user1 user2 user3

This is hard coded in program. It is cool for limited user but whenever number of user increase it create problem. So i want dynamically manage it. Help me out how can i manage dataset and gives label to folder with id to retrieve user information.

Answer (score 0):

[how can i load a directory of png in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947142/how-can-i-load-a-directory-of-png-in-tensorflow?answertab=active#tab-top) Looks similar to your problem,

```
tf.train.match_filenames_once("/home/xxx/Desktop/stackoverflow/images/*/*.png"))
```

instead try this :

```
tf.train.match_filenames_once("/your/path/Data/Train/user*"))
```